# using group_concat with a function()

Tags: php, function, group-concat

My problem is that I have a query that with group_concat gets me the result I need. this is the query. And I have already joined 3 tables where table1 has for example people names, table2 has their liked fruit info and table3 has their fruit names. In table2 they are numbered cause of  for the need to alter the data for needs

```
    SELECT 
      table1.row2,
      table2.group_concat(distinct row2) 
    FROM table1
    JOIN table2
    WHERE 
      table1.row1=table2.row1 
    GROUP BY 
      table1.row1
```

The issue is that row 2 gives out numbers (example 1,2) but they are defined in another table into 1=apple and 2=orange
So i use a function with defines that

```
    function fruit($value){
        if ($value==1){
            $result=apple;
        }elseif($value==2){
            $result=orange;
        }
    return $result;
    }
```

So as i want to have a column where instead of "1,2" is "apple, orange" I use the function in the fetching results. Issue is that i dont get "apple,orange", instead I get "apple"

Seems like it just zeros my grouping

Looked for answers but couldnt find any. anybody ???

Answer (score 0):

You can join onto this other table to get the names in the query:

```
SELECT row1,group_concat(distinct table2.name) FROM table 
LEFT JOIN table2 ON (table.row2 = table2.id)
GROUP by row1
```

Obviously you'll need to change `table2.id` and `table2.name` to something appropriate.

As for the function you aren't returning `$result` so any calls to this will return `NULL`. Simply add:

```
return $result;
```

Comment: Hmmm, will try that but I also edited my first question. Forgot to mention that i already have joined multiple tables

Comment: Yeah, that did the trick. making another join and losing my initali grouping and setting a grouping to the table3 row